# Solving/simplifying a trig expression

Tags: trigonometry

My problem sheet says that $\tan a= 5/12$ and $a \in {\rm Q\,III}$ ($a$'s in quadrant III). Using this information, I am to solve/simplify the expression

$\quad \quad \cos\left(\frac{1}{2}a\right)$ where $\tan\:a=\frac{5}{12}$ and $a \in {\rm Q\,III}$

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm just not getting?

(Also, it's in radians and $\cos a=-12/13$ because I'm working with a 5, 12, 13 triangle.)

Comment: Again, this does not appear to be related to the software product *Mathematica* by Wolfram Research.  Shall I move your post to [Math.SE]?

Comment: @Precalcyay: hint $cos 2x =2cos^2x - 1$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $\tan\:a=\frac{5}{12}$, then

$$\sec^2{a}=1+\tan^2{a}=\frac{169}{144}$$